# Cannot autowire argument $blog of "App\Controller\BlogController::edit()": it references class "App\Entity\Blog" but no such service exists

Tags: symfony, runtime-error, symfony4, autowired

Here I'm trying to edit the post but it shows this autowire error.....even everything seems to be right in the codes......

[image]

here is the controller file with edit function which i used to edit my symfony project....i don't think there is any syntax error......its seems to be like something else

****src/Controller/BlogController.php****

```html
 
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection;

use App\Repository\BlogRepository;
use App\Entity\Blog;
use App\Form\BlogType;


class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
 /**
    * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
    * @param Request $request
    * @param Blog $blog
    * @return Response
    */
    public function edit(Request $request, Blog $blog, $id): Response
    {          
        $form = $this->createForm(BlogType::class, $blog);
        $form->handleRequest($request);      

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $blog = $entityManager->getRepository(Blog::class)->find($id);
            
        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            $file = $request->files->get('blog')['featureImage'];
            if($file != null){
                
                $uploads_directory = $this->getParameter('uploads_directory');
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(
                    $uploads_directory,
                    $filename
                );
                $blog->setFeatureImage($filename);
            }
            
                
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($blog);
            $entityManager->flush();    

            $this->addFlash('success', 'blog edited successfully!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('blog');
        }

        return $this->render('blog/edit.html.twig', [ 
            'edit' => $form->createView(),
            'blog' => $blog,
            'id' => $blog->getid(),
        ]);
    } 

}
```

```
here is my blog entity file codes......
```

**src/Entity/Blog.php**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Controller\Admin\BlogController;
use App\Repository\BlogRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="blogs")
 * @UniqueEntity("blogTitle")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=BlogRepository::class)
 */
class Blog
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The blog title of category is required.")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The short description of category is required.")
     * @Assert\Length(min=500)
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $shortDescription;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The description of category is required.")
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "The feature image of category is required.")
     */
    private $featureImage;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getShortDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->shortDescription;
    }

    public function setShortDescription(string $shortDescription): self
    {
        $this->shortDescription = $shortDescription;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFeatureImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->featureImage;
    }

    public function setFeatureImage(?string $featureImage): self
    {
        $this->featureImage = $featureImage;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
and here is my template where i used to create edit botton to edit post...
```

**template: blog/index.html.twig**

```html
   

{% for blog in blog %}
    <tr>
     <td>{{ blog.id }}</td>
     <td>{{ blog.title }}</td>
     <a href="{{ path('edit', {'id': blog.id, 'title': blog.title}) }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">{{ 'Edit'|trans }}</a>
    </tr>
   {% else %}
```

Comment: @Bossman It is actually quite normal to inject entities into Symfony controller action methods.  Nothing to do with services.

Comment: @Cerad Yes you're right. But in this context i don't think he has too. I could be wrong though..

Comment: @Bossman bro you might be right but the thing is i'm trying to edit so if i'll not inject the entity how can i pull the submitted value to edit it.......

Comment: I would do this first `$blog = $entityManager->getRepository(Blog::class)->find($id);` then create the form with `$form = $this->createForm(BlogType::class, $blog);`. That will pull your data to the forms `data_class`.

Thus, eliminating the need to inject the entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comment. This is what i would do so you don't have to inject your Entity. Let the Form class handle it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection;

use App\Repository\BlogRepository;
use App\Entity\Blog;
use App\Form\BlogType;


class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
 /**
    * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
    * @param Request $request
    * @return Response
    */
    public function edit(Request $request, $id): Response
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $blog = $entityManager->getRepository(Blog::class)->find($id);
      
        $form = $this->createForm(BlogType::class, $blog);
        $form->handleRequest($request);      
            
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $file = $request->files->get('blog')['featureImage'];
            if($file != null){
                
                $uploads_directory = $this->getParameter('uploads_directory');
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move(
                    $uploads_directory,
                    $filename
                );
                $blog->setFeatureImage($filename);
            }
            
                
            $entityManager->persist($blog);
            $entityManager->flush();    

            $this->addFlash('success', 'blog edited successfully!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('blog');
        }

        return $this->render('blog/edit.html.twig', [ 
            'edit' => $form->createView(),
            'blog' => $blog,
            'id' => $blog->getid(),
        ]);
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using [ParamConverters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html), but you made a mistake by adding both `$blog` and `$id` in your controller method.

Just do this:

```
/**
* @Route("/{id}/edit", name="edit", methods={"GET","POST"})
*/
public function edit(Request $request, Blog $blog): Response
{     

}
```

The same goes for your Twig template. You only have to use the `id`. You should remove `title`:

```
{% for blog in blog %}
<tr>
 <td>{{ blog.id }}</td>
 <td>{{ blog.title }}</td>
 <a href="{{ path('edit', {'id': blog.id }) }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">{{ 'Edit'|trans }}</a>
</tr>
{% else %}
```

Bonus-suggestion: I removed the `@return` and `@param` docblocks. Since you're using return/param types, those add no value.

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't worked anymore...…..its gives the same error